# Rows to columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, pivot

I have a table like

```
cases    open/close    count 
-----------------------------
A        open          10       
A        close         15
B        open          6
B        close         4
```

I need to get a result table that is like

```
cases   total     open     close  
---------------------------------
A       25        10       15
B       10        6        4
```

Any ideas about this?

Comment: forgot to mention... there are other columns at the source table that have to be carried to the final table as it is... so... i dont think pivot would work... your suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: I would describe this more as aggregate/grouping not really rows to columns.  You may be able to use a select into Query to do this

Answer (score 4):

This is commonly referred to as a pivot query, converting row into columnar data.  Use:

```
  SELECT t.cases,
         SUM(t.count) AS total,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.open_close = 'open' THEN t.count ELSE 0 END) AS open,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.open_close = 'close' THEN t.count ELSE 0 END) AS close
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.cases
```

Oracle didn't add the ANSI PIVOT (and UNPIVOT) syntax until 11g.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot over the column cases and aggregate sum of count.

Comment: PIVOT was intoduced in 11g, the OP specifies 10g in the tags